# Rasterizing point layer with multiple features falling inside raster cell using GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, gdal-rasterize

How to make a raster with values that are the sum of all points inside each raster cell?

The burn value is a specific attribute.

Using gdal_rasterize or gdal.RasterizeLayer(), the resulting raster only has the value of a random (or probably the first or last) point inside a raster cell. I’ve already tried gdal_rasterize option ALL_TOUCHED, but it does not change the behaviour.

Comment: How do you expect or require multiple values in a single cell to be aggregated? Sum, mean, first ,last, etc...In the end, multiple points will have to be converted to a single value, as you are seeing.

Comment: Raster value should be the _sum_ of the attributes of the points falling inside the raster cell.

Comment: Oh you did specify that, I read that sentence a few times and still didn't see it...sorry!

Comment: Try setting the rasterize option MERGE_ALG=ADD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding 'MERGE_ALG=ADD' to the list of options to gdal.RasterizeLayer() did the trick, thanks to [kyle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/10353/kyle). An example:

```
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], src_layer, options = ['MERGE_ALG=ADD'])
```

This is documented in http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html.