# Outputting mean value when multiple input points fall within cell using QGIS Rasterize?

Tags: qgis, rasterization

Using QGIS 3.8.2, I rasterize a Geopackage vector point layer using the Raster > Conversion > Rasterize tool, with output to a .tif file.

However, where multiple input points are within a single output cell, the tool will only output the value of one point.  I need the *average* of all points within each cell.

[Rasterizing point layer with multiple features falling inside raster cell using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167757) describes how to *sum* multiple input points into one output raster cell.  In this case, the solution was to incorporate the option *MERGE_ALG=ADD*.  However, a review of the current [gdal_rasterize documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html) makes no mention of *MERGE_ALG*.  Furthermore, that was done within the context of Python, which I know nothing about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gdal_rasterize option for adding values from all points within each cell is `-add`. There is no option to do other types of stats - such as average. You can use SAGA Rasterize algorithm from QGIS, which gives you options such as minimum/ maximum/ mean/ first last to deal with multiple values.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I suppose that the MERGE_ALD option used in the previous post has been deprecated.

Comment: Sadly, the SAGA Rasterize tool does not have an "add" option... or a "count" option, which would be handy to calculate point frequency in each cell.